# Call methods from a list of Action

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code:

```
        public async Task Execute()
        {
            _count = 0;
            _total = 2; //I need to update this every time I add a new code block below.

            //1st code block
            _progressCallback("Downloading Inspections", _count / _total);
            //do stuff
            _count += 1;

            //2nd code block
            _progressCallback("Downloading Profiles", _count / _total);
            //do stuff
            _count += 1;
        }
```

I need to keep adding more code blocks, which means I need to keep updating `_total`.

I thought about doing something like so I don't need to keep updating `_total`, I can get it from the Count of the `List<Action>`:

```
List<Action> functions = new List<Action>();
functions.Add(() => FirstCodeBlock(_count, functions.Count));
```

Obviously this won't work because `functions.Count` is only accurate after all the `Action`s have been added.

Is there some way of writing this code so that I can add blocks of code without having to remember to update `_total`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just populate the list ahead of time.

If you store your actions in a `Dictionary<string,Action>` you can store the messages in there too, which makes it easier to iterate over them in a general fashion.

```
public void DownloadInspections()
{
    //Code goes here
}

public void DownloadProfiles()
{
    //Code goes here
}

public async Task Execute()
{
    var list = new Dictionary<string,Action>
    {
        { "Downloading inspections", DownloadInspections },
        { "Downloading profiles",    DownloadProfiles    }
    };

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        //Display progress using the string included as the dictionary entry's key
        _progressCallback(item.Key, _count++ / list.Count);

        //Execute the action, which is stored in the dictionary entry's value
        item.Value();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your List approach seems like it should work.  `functions.Count` in the lambda isn't evaluated until the lambda is invoked, so if you add all of the actions before you start invoking them, you should be fine.

This is an example of a *closure*.  Since `functions` is declared outside of the lambda, the compiler does some magic to allow it to be evaluated at invocation time.

Comment: Totally forgot about the closure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine. The `() => FirstCodeBlock(_count, functions.Count)` is only executed when you invoke the action. Try this example code:

```
List<Action> functions = new List<Action>();
functions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(functions.Count));
functions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(functions.Count));
functions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(functions.Count));
functions.ForEach(function => function());
```

When I run this I get this:

```
3
3
3
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you don't need `_count` in the activities block,otherwise remove the `_count++ / _total`.

Because you always have to describe/specify the string'ed named operations, use that as your total. And keep to the pattern.

```
int _count = 0;
var operations = new List<string>()
{
    "Downloading Inspections",
    "Downloading Profiles"
};

var _total = operations.Count();

_progressCallback(operations[_count], _count++ / _total);

...

_progressCallback(operations[_count], _count++ / _total);

...
```